# Injecting methods in prototype instead of assigning

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm reading the [JSVerbalExpression](https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/JSVerbalExpressions/blob/master/VerbalExpressions.js) source code, and i'm trying to understand why the authors are injecting methods in the prototype of the construction function, instead of just assigning them:

```
function VerbalExpression() {
    var verbalExpression = new RegExp();

    // Add all the class methods
    VerbalExpression.injectClassMethods(verbalExpression);

    // Return the new object.
    return verbalExpression;
}

/**
* @param {RegExp} verbalExpression An instance of RegExp on which to add VerbalExpressions methods
* @return {RegExp} A new instance of RegExp with injected methods
*/
VerbalExpression.injectClassMethods = function injectClassMethods(verbalExpression) {
    var method;
    // Loop over all the prototype methods
    for (method in VerbalExpression.prototype) {
        // Make sure this is a local method.
        if (VerbalExpression.prototype.hasOwnProperty(method)) {
            // Add the method
            verbalExpression[method] = VerbalExpression.prototype[method];
        }
    }

    return verbalExpression;
};
```

Is it related with performance?

Thanks.

Comment: They are assigning the methods in `verbalExpression[method] = VerbalExpression.prototype[method];`. I don't quite understand what you are confused about.

Comment: HM, i'm not understand what is for

Comment: They are extending a regular expression object with custom properties.